# Gparted warning: Unable to find mountpoint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gparted, uuid

I've got a working Ubuntu 8.04 system, but when I went to partition a new disk I saw a warning on my boot partition.  It's the orange triangle with an exclamation point, and the error is:

```
Unable to find mountpoint
Unable to read the contents of this filesystem!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
```

The fstab entry for my system disk (sde1) is:

```
# boot partition
UUID=f97ccec0-bac2-4550-bf9a-2752effe3875 / ext3 relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

However "sudo blkid" says:

```
/dev/sde1: UUID="f8f65183-cc63-4009-a351-d1159d28f6cf" TYPE="ext3"
```

So I think the problem is that my fstab entry has the wrong UUID (probably from a previous disk), so my boot disk is never properly mounted.  In which case the solution would be to change the UUID in fstab to match the blkid UUID.  Is that correct?  I'd like some confirmation before I make the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the UUID did the trick, but I also had to change the UUID in grub's menu.lst config file to match the actual UUID of the partition.  After that, the gparted error was gone.